# flash video player doesn't display in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I cannot see flash video player in IE in this website: [www.donatellabernardi.ch/drupal](http://www.donatellabernardi.ch/drupal)
It works in other browsers: For example click on the article 'Test Jacques' and scroll down, you'll see an empty space instead of the video.

Update: this is the code of the video object.. why is this code not working in IE ?

```
<object data="[site-url]/videoPlayer/bin-debug/videoPlayer.swf?file=[site-url]/[filefield-filepath]" height="445" id="movie_player_1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640">
<param name="bgColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="autoplay" value="true" />
<param name="flashvars" value="[site-url]/[filefield-filepath]"/>
</object>
```

**Update**: using swfobject:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {
 name1: "[site-url]/[filefield-filepath]",
};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("[site-url]/[filefield-filepath]", "[filefield-fid]", "640", "445", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
<div id="[filefield-fid]"></div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

`file=http://www.donatellabernardi.ch/drupal/sites/default/files/files/projects/Test jacques/Video/testVideo.flv`

to the flashvars parameter.

Also, you've got `0=movie_player_1` in flashvars which is invalid. Flash variable can't be prefixed with a number or furthermore, be of a numeric type. Try working this out and see if it resolves the case.

**UPDATE:** it could easily be that the Drupal video module (that I'm assuming you are deploying) is misconfigured or has a malfunction.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. I've done what you suggested and now it works in Firefox too. Still IE gives issues (it doesn't display at all)

Comment: ps. The video module should be fine.. it works perfectly in all browser except IE.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what I meant, the module fails to establish the right codebase for the IE.

If I recall correctly from some historic milestone in Flash embedding, IE expects a **classid** attribute for the object tag and it's currently missing in the above code of yours. You could try that as well, 

All in all, it's not a bad idea to implement SWFObject and forget about this embedding madness, see http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/
Your site very likely relies on JavaScript anyway, right?

Comment: I've tried adding classid, but still not working. What should be its value ? I've copied the value they use in swfobject samples.

Comment: I've also tried swfobject but still not working. I've tried both dynamically added and statically added content (from swfobject tutorials). I've added the code in the question, it doesn't work. I cannot add the javascript on top of the page but just before the object element, maybe this is the reason.

Comment: I think classid value was a Flash Player version reference for ActiveX. 

Try replacing the object tag with only the following SWFObject code (and make sure you've got SWFObject JS included in the header): 

<script type="text/javascript">
        var params = {menu: "false", scale: "noscale", flashvars:"file=[site-url]/[filefield-filepath]"};
        swfobject.embedSWF("[site-url]/videoPlayer/bin-debug/videoPlayer.swf?file=[site-url]/[filefield-filepath]", "movie_player_1", "640", "445", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", null, params);
</script>

Comment: yuhuu, finally it works. I have added a parent div to your last code: <div id="movie_player_1"></div> and then the script. thanks for help